# create custom breakpoint for media query

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I'm trying to create some common breakpoints for mediaqueries in my angular app. I'm using scss. I repeat this 3 lines everywhere and I want to improve it:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 959px), 
  screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 599px) {

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 959px) {

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 599px) {
```

I want to create some variables for including this, but I'm not getting it, it should be something like:

```
$mobile = "screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 959px), 
  screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 599px)"
$landscape_mobile = "screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 959px)"
$portrait_mobile = "screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 599px)"
```

is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are defined using a `:`, not `=`.

You can use them this way:

```
$mobile: "screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 959px), 
  screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 599px)";
$landscape_mobile: "screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 959px)";
$portrait_mobile: "screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 599px)";

@media #{$mobile} { ... }
@media #{$landscape_mobile} { ... }
@media #{$portrait_mobile} { ... }
```

> Note the interpolation syntax `#{}`.
>   [More about Sass interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mixin and use it whenever you want

```
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @if $point == desktop {
    @media (min-width: 1400px) { @content; }
  }
}

// Use like this
div {
  @include breakpoint(desktop) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```